# How to display the utf-8 and unicode value of chinese character with php?

Tags: php, unicode, encoding, utf-8

In python, I can get a *utf-8* content and Unicode of Chinese character.

```
python version 3.4
>>> print("你".encode("utf-8"))
b'\xe4\xbd\xa0'
>>> print("你".encode("unicode-escape"))
b'\\u4f60'
```

How do I display the utf-8 and unicode value of `你`(means you in english)
in the web with php? How do I get the same output `'\xe4\xbd\xa0'` and `\\u4f60` in firefox with `php` as I can with python?

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13496271/how-to-properly-display-chinese-characters-in-php

Comment: no sir ,i want to get the value of chinese character which expressed in utf-8 or unicode, not to properly display Chinese characters in PHP.

Comment: Maybe you can update the title and the tags of your question so it reflects the content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first example is displaying the utf-8 encoded bytes; therefore, assuming the string is utf-8 encoded, you can simply print the hexadecimal ACSII values for each character.

```
$str = "你";

foreach (str_split($str) as $byte) {
    echo '\\x'.str_pad(dechex(ord($byte)), 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
}

// prints: \xe4\xbd\xa0
```

The second line is printing the [Unicode code point](http://unicode.org/glossary/#code_point) for the character. Since php strings are only single byte, we must first decode the bytes to access the code point, then format the hexadecimal number.

Based on the [WHATWG Encoding Standard](https://encoding.spec.whatwg.org) we can make a [utf-8 decoder](https://encoding.spec.whatwg.org/#utf-8-decoder) to decode code points including [supplementary code points](http://unicode.org/glossary/#supplementary_code_point).

```
// Decodes a utf-8 encoded string and returns an array
// of code points or null if there was an error
// https://encoding.spec.whatwg.org/#utf-8-decoder
function decode_utf8($str)
{
    $code_point = 0;
    $bytes_needed = 0;
    $bytes_seen = 0;

    $lower_boundary = 0x80;
    $upper_boundary = 0xbf;

    $code_points = array();

    for ($i = 0, $len = strlen($str); $i < $len; $i++) {
        $byte = ord($str[$i]);

        if ($bytes_needed == 0) {
            if ($byte >= 0x00 and $byte <= 0x7f) {
                $code_points[] = $byte;
            } elseif ($byte >= 0xc2 and $byte <= 0xdf) {
                $bytes_needed = 1;
                $code_point = $byte - 0xc0;
            } elseif ($byte >= 0xe0 and $byte <= 0xef) {
                if ($byte == 0xe0) {
                    $lower_boundary = 0xa0;
                }
                if ($byte == 0xed) {
                    $upper_boundary = 0x9f;
                }

                $bytes_needed = 2;
                $code_point = $byte - 0xe0;
            }  elseif ($byte >= 0xf0 and $byte <= 0xf4) {
                if ($byte == 0xf0) {
                    $lower_boundary = 0x90;
                }
                if ($byte == 0xf4) {
                    $upper_boundary = 0x8f;
                }

                $bytes_needed = 3;
                $code_point = $byte - 0xf0;
            }  else {
                return;
            }

            $code_point = $code_point << (6 * $bytes_needed);
            continue;
        }

        if ($byte < $lower_boundary or $byte > $upper_boundary) {
            return;
        }

        $lower_boundary = 0x80;
        $upper_boundary = 0xbf;

        $bytes_seen++;
        $code_point += ($byte - 0x80) << (6 * ($bytes_needed - $bytes_seen));

        if ($bytes_seen != $bytes_needed) {
            continue;
        }

        $code_points[] = $code_point;

        $code_point = 0;
        $bytes_needed = 0;
        $bytes_seen = 0;
    }

    if ($bytes_needed != 0) {
        return;
    }

    return $code_points;
}
```

Once we decode the code points, we convert them to hexadecimal with `dechex`. Then, using `str_pad`, we left pad them with zeros. If the code point is in the basic multilingual plain, we pad it so that it is four characters long, otherwise we make it six characters long. Finally, we prepend the `\u` at the beginning.

```
$str = '你';

foreach (decode_utf8($str) as $code_point) {
    echo '\\u'.str_pad(dechex($code_point), $code_point>0xffff?6:4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
// prints: \u4f60
```

It also work for characters out side the basic multilingual plain, such as [CJK Ideograph Extensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_Unified_Ideographs_Extension_B).

```
$str = ''; // U+020000

foreach (decode_utf8($str) as $code_point) {
    echo '\\u'.str_pad(dechex($code_point), $code_point>0xffff?6:4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
// prints: \u020000
```

Comment: Note `utf8_to_unicode` fails for characters outside the Basic Multilingual Plane (ie four-byte UTF-8 sequences).

Comment: how to fix it when characters outside the Basic Multilingual Plane?

Comment: @bobince Added a more thorough utf-8 decoder for supplementary code points.

Comment: echo '\\x'.sprintf("%'02x",ord($byte)); is more clear than  echo '\\x'.str_pad(dechex(ord($byte)), 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);