# Can't get the Chinese value out of an array

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to get a value from an array. But it always returns non-sense.
Is it because it's a Chinese string? How can I get the first value out of "$custom_field_value[ 'value' ]"? I tried so many ways and really can't figure it out... Thank you very much for your help!!

```
foreach ( $rating_result[ 'custom_field_values' ] as $custom_field_value ) {
    var_dump($custom_field_value[ 'value' ]);
    //return: string(15) "蠻認真的！"string(5) "okok!"
    $value_text      = stripslashes( $custom_field_value[ 'value' ][0] );
    echo $value_text;
    //return: �o                    
}
```

Comment: have you looked at iconv and using the ignore flag?

Comment: try encoding your string to UTF-8 with http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php before passing to stripslashes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to properly display Chinese characters in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13496271/how-to-properly-display-chinese-characters-in-php)

Comment: @Florian If the first var_dump is displaying the right characters, then it's not a header issue.

Comment: I trid  to  echo utf8_encode($value_text);  It still returns no-sense... Or, did I target the wrong thing? I am a php beginner... Am I writing a valid code? Thank you all!

Comment: Do this before stripslashes.

Comment: I put echo utf8_encode($custom_field_value[ 'value' ][0] ); echo $custom_field_value[ 'value' ][0]; before the stripslashes, within the foreach. They both return non-sense, è�èooo.

Comment: utf8_encode only encodes from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8. So you need to use mb_convert_encoding.